# How do i store information (chapter titles) from multiple XPath locations with slight differences, into a list with python?

Tags: python, list, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to gather a list of chapter titles which I can then use to create folders with the correct names to store the data I want from each chapter. I have found the XPath of where the titles are stored in the pages HTML using the Inspect tool in Google Chrome, and each name has a slightly different path that it is stored in, what methods can I use to get these titles that can be repeated without knowing the exact XPath of each of them and store them in a list for later use?

For example:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/section/article/section[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[5]/div[1]/span[2]/span     ## chapter 5

/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/section/article/section[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[6]/div[1]/span[2]/span     ## chapter 6
```

The only differences in the XPath between the two is "/li[5]/" and "/li[6]/" with each chapter having its own number, and the chapter title contained in the final span. Is it possible to make a process that would be able to navigate each of the paths and grab the chapter titles, without knowing the specific XPath of each beforehand and without knowing how many chapters there are going to be?

Any help you can give will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Now that I've thought about it some more would using regex to find out what the span that contains the title is called, be the best option?

Comment: In the list tag, there is a part that has  `data-description="5. Example Chapter Name"` and using the regex `(data-description=)(.\d..)(.+)(")` i can identify it

Comment: although `(data-description=)(.+)(")` is a simpler version

Comment: Maybe you should post a sample of your data so we can build a generic expression which will select all the titles. You should prefer XPath over regex for this kind of work.